# What happens if a machine gets a SYN/ACK packet without sending initial SYN packet?

Tags: tcp, connection

I'm thinking of a situation where an attacker manipulates a SYN packet that was sent from A's source IP address to B.

The server will receive the packet and think it's a legitimate packet, and send a SYN/ACK packet as a response to B instead of A.

Upon receiving a SYN/ACK packet from a server, as B, what would send back? Would it send RST packet to indicate that it's an error? or SYN/ACK packet thinking a server is trying to establish a connection?

I'm trying to think what would an attacker gain from this type of attack..

This is not a homework. It's just my curiosity as I begin to learn this TCP/IP connection establishment.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  We like folks trying to learn, but on-topic questions here are supposed to be in a professional context which isn't clear here.

Comment: maybe http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ would be closer.

Comment: It depends on the operating system, if a service is listening on that port, local firewall rules, hardware firewalls, and finally how the syn/ack is constructed. FWIW, nmap has this capability.

Answer (score 5):

If a session does not exist for the source/destination pair, the packet will not be accepted by B. In the case of a SYN-ACK packet, B will reply with a RST (reset) packet, telling the server that no connection was initiated.